# R running very slowly when importing and manipulating 100,000 KB dataset

Tags: r, performance, import, freeze

I'm working with a dataset in R with dimensions of about 7000 x 5000. The file size is about 100,000 KB. It takes about half an hour to load it into R. When I try to create a correlation table in order to run a PCA, R freezes. Then I have to reopen it and import the data again.

I'm surprised that it's so slow with a dataset of this size. I thought datasets had to be much larger to affect the speed to this degree. I'm using a Microsoft Surface Pro 3.

Does anyone have any ideas for why this might be happening and what I can do about it? Is it my laptop? Or is this kind of thing common with datasets of this size?

Edit in response to comments: My computer has 8 GB RAM. This is the code I am using:

```
nlsy_training_set <- read_excel("nlsy training set.xlsx")
df <- nlsy_training_set
full <- df[,2:4886]
corf <- cor(full)
corf <- fill.NAs(full, data = NULL, all.covs = FALSE, contrasts.arg = NULL)
corf <- as.data.frame(corf)
pcaf <- principal(corf, nfactors = 100, rotate = "varimax")$loadings
dfpcaf <- as.data.frame(pcaf)
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using for importing (from which format?) and for computing PCA. Are there missing values in your data? What is the amount of RAM on your computer?

Comment: Also, can you kindly check if there are many other processes or applications running in your system and the amount of memory , cpu utilized by those.

Comment: I updated my original post @F.Privé. I have tried to remove the missing values from my data. Could that be affecting the speed? The code I posted still hasn't run.

Comment: @KarthikBalaguru The only program I have open that is using more CPU than RStudio is Chrome, and it's only using 2-5% at any given moment.

Comment: @melbez For missing values, it is just that some faster alternatives for computing PCA do not allow for missing values.

Comment: Please provide the packages your using and some reproducible data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This was very slow because I was using read_excel and had converted the original data file into an Excel workbook format. Once I used read.csv and used the original csv format, I was able to import the data into R relatively quickly.

Using read.csv works better than read_excel for large datasets.